# "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited" after updating discord.py

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

The discord bot I made a year ago and deployed to Heroku has worked until now. However, after changing some cogs and updating python to version 3.9.10, I get the following warning in the Heroku logs:

```
app[worker.1]: /app/m_bot.py:120: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
app[worker.1]: client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
app[worker.1]: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
app[worker.1]: Bot is ready.
app[api]: Build succeeded>
```

The 120 line block is:

```py
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        # cut of the .py from the file name
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

The bot goes online but doesn't respond to any command. I haven't made any other changes apart from what was listed above.

It works when I run my bot on my PC, so I suspect it might be a version problem.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Explanation

As of discord.py version 2.0, `Bot.load_extension` is now a coroutine and has to be awaited. This is to allow `Cog` subclasses to override `cog_unload` with a coroutine.

### Code

`await` must be used in front of `client.load_extension`, as shown:

```py
await client.load_extension("your_extension")
```

**In each of your cogs:**

Replace the standard `setup` function with an asynchronous one:

```py
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(YourCog(bot))
```

---

If you want to use the normal convention for adding extensions, you'll need to use the following code:

**In your client's file:**

```py
async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            # cut off the .py from the file name
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

You should also wrap your login in an asynchronous 'main' function, where you would call this function. **Note that the code below does not setup logging, [you need to do so yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732135/no-errors-outputing-after-i-started-using-cogs-in-discord-py-2-0)**:

```py
async def main():
    async with client:
        await load_extensions()
        await client.start('your_token')

asyncio.run(main())
```

These two functions replace the old way:

```py
client.run("your_token")
```

along with the code you posted in your question.

### Reference

[discord.py 2.0 async changes](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/6706e1c8f23ac27c98cee4dd985c8120) (Thank you ChrisDewa for mentioning this in your comment)

Comment: I followed these steps, but unfortunately I always just keep getting the error `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` on the `asyncio.run(main())` line. Any suggestions? I tried the nest_asyncio hack, see https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio, which fixes the error, but then just breaks other things. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: @BobSmith I would check for any existing questions, and if none exist pertaining to this issue, I would recommend to make a new question. It makes it a lot easier to answer :)