# Bot base.load_extentstion was never awaited error message discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So when I try to run my discord bot I get this error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
2022-04-30T22:38:44.714019+00:00 app[worker.1]: client.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# When running this file, if it is the 'main' file
# I.E its not being imported from anther python file run this
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py") and not file.startswith("_"):
         client.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
client.run("random token here")
```

I tried to read the other stackoverflow [article on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504627/runtimewarning-coroutine-botbase-load-extension-was-never-awaited-after-upd) but when I tried to do what it said it told me I cannot use await outside of function. But when I fix it using

```
async def main():
    # do other async things
    await my_async_function()

    # start the client
    async with client:
        await client.start(TOKEN)
```

and do asycnio.run(main()) it does not work and tells me that

```
 RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: You're probably running on discord.py2.0.0a, your `client.load_extension` needs to be executed asynchronously using the `await` keyword. You should have a look on this article: [Migrating to v2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/migrating.html)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the `await cannot be used outside of function` error in the code of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in 2.0 loading extensions is async. You need to use `client.start()` with `asyncio`.

As the error says, you can't have an already running event loop. Discord has its own event loop to manage things, so you'll have to use `get_event_loop` to get it instead. Then, `run_until_complete` suffices here because nothing else needs to run.

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    # if you need to, initialize other things, such as aiohttp
    await client.load_extension('my_extension')  # change to whatever you need
    await client.start('token')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```