# Error when trying to run discord.py with asynchronous functions on cog_loader

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I am trying to build my first discord.py bot on a docker container. But when running it the traceback gave me the following error on the cogs_loader:
[image]

I used the following articles to try to fix the error, but I failed when trying refactor my code with their solution:

[Bot base.load_extentstion was never awaited error message discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072753/bot-base-load-extentstion-was-never-awaited-error-message-discord-py)

["RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited" after updating discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504627/runtimewarning-coroutine-botbase-load-extension-was-never-awaited-after-upd)

This is my "client" file:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = Bot(owner_id=env.owner_id, command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

async def load_extensions():
    await bot.load_extension('bot.cogs.commands')
    await bot.load_extension('bot.cogs.owner')


async def main():
    await load_extensions()
    await bot.start(env.TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

This is my `__init__.py` file for the cogs (setup):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = Bot(owner_id=env.owner_id, command_prefix='.', intents=intents)


async def setup(bot):
    """
    Init bot's cogs
    """
    await bot.add_cog(Commands(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(Owner(bot))
```

This is the traceback when running `__main__.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/GitHub/Mamey_bot/bot/__main__.py", line 83, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/GitHub/Mamey_bot/bot/__main__.py", line 62, in main
    await load_extensions()
  File "D:/GitHub/Mamey_bot/bot/__main__.py", line 57, in load_extensions
    await bot.load_extension('bot.cogs.commands')
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

If I rewrite `main()` in `__main__.py` like in the first article:

```py
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(env.TOKEN)
```

I would get a different traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/GitHub/Mamey_bot/bot/__main__.py", line 84, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/GitHub/Mamey_bot/bot/__main__.py", line 62, in main
    async with bot:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

How can I fix this?

If I don't use asynchronous functions when running the bot in the container, the bot will get online, but the commands wont work.

Comment: what discord.py version are you using?

Comment: Make sure your docker is using python version `>3.8` and you have setup discord version correctly in your `requirements.txt` if pip isn't installing the correct version which is `>2.0.0`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm using v: 1.7.3

Comment: @3nws My .Dockerfile has the commands: `RUN python3 -m pip install -U discord.py` for discord.py and its installing python 3.8.

Comment: you need 2.0.0 not 1.7.3 @Mamey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my Dockerfile was installing the wrong discord.py version.

#### Inside the container

In the docker container `RUN python3 -m pip install -U discord.py` was installing Discord.py 2.0.1, and that's why the traceback was giving me "load_extension was never awaited" since I was using a deprecated syntax of 1.7.3.

After using the proper command in the Dockerfile: `RUN python3 -m pip install discord.py==1.7.3` the issue disappears and the bot and its commands works perfectly.

#### On my real PC and the refactored code

My real PC/OS (outside the docker container) had the inverse issue: It had installed discord.py 1.7.3 and the refactored code was using discord.py 2.0.1 syntax. After running in the CMD `py -3 -m pip install -U py-cord` the refactored code that I shared in the original question works perfectly.

tl;dr: Need to be more careful on what versions I'm importing.