# No errors outputing after i started using cogs in discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord.py

After i rewritten my extension loading code in discord.py 2.0 everything works fine except if i got any errors in a command it will not send me a error. i have to figure it out with prints this is very annoying tho.
Is there a way to get the errors shown again, I got no error event or listeners

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents().all())
client.remove_command('help')

async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load_extensions()
        await client.start(tokn)
asyncio.run(main())
```

So after i deleted all cogs and nothing was loaded i still got no errors on anything, I also replaced the main function with client.run(token) itl run the bot but the cogs wont load but i get errors on command tho. anyone knows a fix?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) See [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) and [`on_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_error). Also, please see [ask] and [help/on-topic] and [how to format posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Try `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour was changed to use the `logging` framework instead.

Docs example & explanation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html

Seeing as you're not using `Client.run()`, but rather `Client.start()`, there's no default handler being provided, so you have to do it yourself.

After following the example in the docs page linked above, your errors should get logged in a file named `discord.log` (or however you decided to name it).

If you'd like it to output to `stdout` (or `stderr`) like before, either do that manually in `on_command_error()`, or configure `stderr` as your handler for the logger instead of the `RotatingFileHandler`. This answer explains how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058475/13568999