# Quart discord.py on Heroku : loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, python-asyncio, quart

I am using Quart and Discord.py to build a discord bot.
i run the two with this method.

```
app.app_context()
bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0", port=80))
bot.run(Discord_Dev_Token)
```

i tried to deploy the project into heroku service and it makes a successful deployement but it doesn't work later
when i check the logs i find this error message

```
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191305+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191350+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/mvc.py", line 688, in <module>
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191694+00:00 app[web.1]:     bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0", port=PORT))
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191707+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 108, in __getattr__
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191797+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise AttributeError(msg)
2022-09-10T22:08:17.191827+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook
```

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

From [*Changes to async initialisation in discord.py*](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/6706e1c8f23ac27c98cee4dd985c8120):

> While Client.run still works, accessing the Client.loop attribute will
> now result in an error if it's accessed outside of an async context.
> In order to do any sort of asynchronous initialisation, it is
> recommended to refactor your code out into a "main" function.

**WARNING**: `bot.start` does not provide a logger by default. If you want to see errors (which most people do), you need to set up logging yourself. Please see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732135/no-errors-outputing-after-i-started-using-cogs-in-discord-py-2-0)

### Code

```py
async def main():
    async with bot:
        bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0", port=80))
        await bot.start(Discord_Dev_Token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The code above replaces the old way:

```py
bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0", port=80))
bot.run(Discord_Dev_Token)
```