# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension(extension)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.utils import find
import time
import json

import ztoken

async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open(r"prefix.json", 'r') as f:
        prefixFile = json.load(f)

    try:
        prefix = prefixFile[f"{message.guild.id}"]
    except:
        prefix = "."
    return prefix
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

extensions = ["db", "cogs.admin", "cogs.bank", "cogs.bj", "cogs.coinflip", "cogs.color_guesser", "cogs.crash",
              "cogs.daily", "cogs.economy", "cogs.error_handling", "cogs.lottery", "cogs.miner", "cogs.others", "cogs.quests", "cogs.roulette", "cogs.rps", 
              "cogs.scratch", "cogs.shop", "cogs.slots", "cogs.totals", "cogs.ttt", "cogs.user_settings", "cogs.util", "cogs.vote", "cogs.weeklymonthly",
               "cogs.xp"] # list of cogs to call



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global LogFile

    LogFile = open("Logs.txt", "a")

    print(f"{bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}")
    print(discord.__version__)
    print("Ready...")

    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Do .help for help!"))


# stop user input
# @bot.event
# async def on_message(message):
#   if message.author.bot:
#       return
#   if message.content[0] != '.':
#       return
#   if not await bot.is_owner(message.author):
#       await message.channel.send("Improving bot... Please check back in 1 hour!")
#       return
#   await bot.process_commands(message)

# manually load a cog
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    try:
        
        await bot.load_extension(extension)
        print(f"Loaded {extension}.\n")
        await ctx.send(f"Loaded {extension}")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"{extension} could not be loaded. [{error}]")
        await ctx.send(f"{extension} could not be loaded. [{error}]")


# manually unload a cog
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    try:
        bot.unload_extension(extension)
        print(f"Unloaded {extension}.\n")
        await ctx.send(f"Unloaded {extension}")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"{extension} could not be unloaded. [{error}]")
        await ctx.send(f"{extension} could not be unloaded. [{error}]")


# manually reload a cog
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if extension == 'all':
        lst = bot.extensions.copy()
        for ext in lst:
            try:
                if ext == "cogs.vote":
                    continue
                await bot.reload_extension(ext)
                print(f"Reloaded {ext}.")
                # await ctx.send(f"Reloaded {ext}")
            except Exception as error:
                print(f"{ext} could not be reloaded. [{error}]")
                await ctx.send(f"{ext} could not be reloaded. [{error}]")
        await ctx.send("Finished reloading.")
    else:
        try:
            await bot.reload_extension(extension)
            print(f"Reloaded {extension}.\n")
            await ctx.send(f"Reloaded {extension}")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"{extension} could not be reloaded. [{error}]")
            await ctx.send(f"{extension} could not be reloaded. [{error}]")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
            print(f"Loaded cog: {extension}")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"{extension} could not be loaded. [{error}]")
    # bot.loop.create_task(background_loop())
    bot.run(ztoken.token)
```

My error is : main.py:113: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension(extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I tried adding time.sleep() but wasn't able to solve the problem. I have no idea of the other async. May I ask if someone know something, can you assist me? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load\_extension' was never awaited" after updating discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504627/runtimewarning-coroutine-botbase-load-extension-was-never-awaited-after-upd). Please, in the future, it is much easier to look up the error you are getting as you will often find questions that are similar to yours which may answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bot.load_extension() needs to be awaited by using the "await" keyword, you only forgot to add it the last time you used it in your code.

The ending of your code should look like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in extensions:
        try:
            await bot.load_extension(extension)
**Rest of your code
```