# I keep getting an error in replit when im running my test discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

Whenever i try to run my code for a test bot im using on discord, it comes up with the error

> main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
> bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

My code is

````
import os
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!c", intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"{bot.user} is online!")

  


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
  if filename.endswith(".py"):
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
    
bot.run("im not showing you my bot token lol")```



im using replit btw. what should i do?
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load\_extension' was never awaited" after updating discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504627/runtimewarning-coroutine-botbase-load-extension-was-never-awaited-after-upd)

Answer (score 1):

The error itself tells you what is wrong...

> main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}") RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

The important part is **"coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited"**

discord.py uses coroutines all around so you have to learn to use `await` whenever [it is needed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension).

Long story short, you must use `await` next to `load_extension()`...

Fixed code:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!c", intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"{bot.user} is online!")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
  if filename.endswith(".py"):
    await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
    
bot.run("im not showing you my bot token lol")
```

<s>That should work as long as there are no other problems in your code but it looks fine lol</s>

**Edit:** That actually didn't work because you cannot use `await` outside a function, I came to this problem myself when updating my bot to v2.0, here's my workaround (I got help from people from dpy discord, good place to be aided):

```
async def main():
    async with bot:
        #   This is kinda the same as you had it before
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        await bot.start("token"))

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code should actually work or at least it did work for me lol, if you are following a youtube tutorial *(which you shouldn't)*, it might be outdated so also remember to update your cog's code to keep the async stuff, you might need to update

```
def setup(client): # "client" or "bot", same thing
    client.add_cog(MyCog(client))
```

to

```
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(MyCog(client))
```

For future reference I would advise you to check the docs in https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and look for dpy's discord server to ask questions like this :)

Comment: it came with another error saying "SyntaxError: 'await' outside function" Im really new to python pls help

Comment: Actually after getting into v2.0 myself I found me in the same problem, the workaround I came to was a different one, I will update my answer ASAP