# discord bot to play music, and followed a yt tutorial

Tags: python

```
/home/runner/AdequateEmbarrassedAmoeba/music.py:48: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  client.add_cog(music(client))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2022-10-24 12:01:22 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-10-24 12:01:23 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 1b5daa4ed7ffc36b3a15e264a51cf46e).
```

I was making a discord bot to play music and found a yt tutorial showing how to make one, and followed it but two types of errors, one was a tracemalloc and the other was that i needed to await the function BotBase.add_cog, regarding the second error, idk where to await it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self,client):
    self.client= client

@commands.command()

async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You need to join a voice channel!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
@commands.command()
async def stop(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_Options) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,
        **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)

@commands.command()
async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused")

@commands.command()
async def resume(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resumed")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: You need to add an await line.
Check this one out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504627/runtimewarning-coroutine-botbase-load-extension-was-never-awaited-after-upd

Answer (score 0):

You need to await in your last line, which is also mentioned in the error message.

So, change this

```
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

to this

```
def setup(client):
  await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

But both of these are just warnings, so you should be able to ignore them but they could lead to problems later on. 
Regarding the tracemalloc, you can enable it to trace what memory the object allocates. ([HOW](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html))

Comment: i did change the code but theres a new error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import music
  File "/home/runner/AdequateEmbarrassedAmoeba/music.py", line 51
    await client.add_cog(music(client))
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

Comment: Oh sorry, of course the setup function needs to be async then.
So, `async def setup(client)`

Comment: alright the error's gone but a new thing has come up, the commands arent being 'found'

`2022-10-25 10:11:29 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
2022-10-25 10:11:31 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found`

Comment: You seem to have you function decorators wrong. Check out this article: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-make-discord-bot-commands-in-python-2cae39cbfd55

Comment: apparently you need to initialize the bot first and the add `@bot.command()` as function decorator

Comment: https://mystb.in/PunkLeedsCompiled

heres the main and music files ,so i have to initialize the bot and change function decorator?

Comment: yes exactly. And also change your discord token, if that is your real one

Comment: if this answered your question, please also mark it as an answer